# How to save data in my global variable (undefined value)

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I want to save typeP into typePackage
I have my function :

```
typePackage :any =[];
getTypeUnity(){
   this.typePackage=this.api.consultasByID({
      cquery:10001,
      campo:'ctipopaquete;descripcion',
      parametros:''
    },function(success,datos){
        if(success){
          let type : any={ctipopaquete:Number,descripcion:String};
          let typeP : any=[];
          for(let k in datos.DAT){
            type.ctipopaquete = datos.DAT[k].ctipopaquete;
            type.descripcion = datos.DAT[k].descripcion;
            typeP.push(type)
            type = {ctipopaquete:Number,descripcion:String};
          } 
             this.typePackage = typeP; // error undefined
        }else console.log("error")
      }); 

}
```

When set "typePackage", it is undefined.
You can help me as I set the typeP variable in typePackage

Comment: use an arrow function

Comment: is this method part of a class? How is typePackage used? You seem to be doing an asynchronous call to retrieve it. It would probably be better if you move all this in a service and use an observable to notify when you have the value loaded. Otherwise you'll code using the variable before it's read.

Comment: @toskv yes, is part of a class!! I want to set the variable typeP in type typePackage anyway.

Comment: I used `var that = this`